# how to hide too long texts in div elements?

Tags: css

How can you hide the overflow in a div?

Here, the text wraps to a new line if it is longer than the div.

```css
#truncateLongTexts {
    width: 50px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    overflow-y: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div id="truncateLongTexts">
    test test test test
</div>
```

Comment: @JohnnyCraig - There is no such thing as 'overflow:none'

Comment: thanks rob. my mistake, it happens but instead of just telling people what there isnt, you should also include what there is.`overflow:hidden;`

Answer (score 44):

Maybe the CSS property `text-overflow: ellipsis` can help you out with that problem.

Consider this HTML and CSS below:

```html
<div id="truncateLongTexts">
    test test test test
</div>
```

```css
#truncateLongTexts {
    width: 100px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis; /* This is where the magic happens. */
}
```

Answer (score 35):

If you only want to show a single line of text in a fixed width div, give `white-space:nowrap` a go. Together with `overflow:hidden` it will force your browser not to break the line and crop the view to your forced width.

You might also add `text-overflow:ellipsis` to avoid cutting words and letters in half, it adds a nice `...` to the end to show you there's some bits missing. I'm not sure about the browser support though, and I've never tried this one.

Comment: Firefox 7 just came out, it is the first Firefox that supports `text-overflow`. Other browsers support it (even old IEs). See [text-overflow on caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#search=text-overflow). And +1.

Answer (score 13):

You should specify a `height` for your div, `overflow: hidden;` can only hide the vertically overflowing content if there is some kind of defined height.

**In other words:**

> Here the text just wraps down to a new line if the text is **longer than the div**

**But how long is that div actually?**

Please check out [my jsFiddle demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/vfAbR/) that illustrates the difference.

Comment: even when specifying the height, the text still wraps down to a new line.. but there is overflow - yes

Comment: @clarkk Then what are you trying to achieve exactly?

Answer (score 0):

try 
overflow:none;

you didn't mention if you want scrollbars or not.

EDIT:

Sorry I meant overflow:hidden.

Comment: There is NO `none` value for the `overflow` property. See [CSS2 Spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visufx.html#propdef-overflow).