# using CSS to make text disappear when overflow

Tags: html, responsive-design, css

I have created the following header bar on an HTML/CSS page:

```
  <div class="topmenubar" style="position:relative;background:maroon;height:40px;">
    <div id="menupadding" style="position:relative;left:30px;right:30px;">
      <table style="width:100%;">
        <tr>
          <font class="headerfont">
            <td>BeccasMap.com</td>
            <td style="text-align:right;position:relative;right:60px;white-space:nowrap;overflow:hidden;">Best upcoming Tech events in NYC</td>
          </font>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
```

I would like the text "Best upcoming Tech events in NYC" to disappear when the window is resized small, but I'm not sure how to do this.  I've tried the suggestion in [how to hide too long texts in div elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7612125/how-to-hide-too-long-texts-in-div-elements) and it does not work for me.  Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: What is position:relative;left:30px;right:30px;

Comment: creating left and right margins of 30 px on the line of text.  That part is working.

Answer (score 1):

Check this: http://jsfiddle.net/eKgG8/5/

```
@media only screen and (max-width : 400px){
    .limit{
        display:none;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use media queries to totally hide your text if window's width is less than 500px for instance :

```
@media screen and (max-width: 500px)  {
  .hideIfSmall {
    width:0;
    font-size:0;
  }
```

}

```
<div class="topmenubar" style="position:relative;background:maroon;line-height:40px;">
    <div id="menupadding" style="padding:0 30px;">
      <table style="width:100%;">
        <tr>
          <font class="headerfont">
            <td>BeccasMap.com</td>
            <td class="hideIfSmall">Best upcoming Tech events in NYC</td>
          </font>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
```